# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property

Tags: javascript

I was in confused on what earth why its returning an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'outerHTML' of null
>       at delete_row (table_script.js:10)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (table.html:1)`

Can someone help me determine how to fix the error.

**My Code:**

```js
var temp_image;
var temp_title;
var temp_description;



function delete_row(no) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
    document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
  } else
    alert("Data is not deleted");
}


function add() {
  var new_image = document.getElementById("new_image").value;
  var new_title = document.getElementById("new_title").value;
  var new_description = document.getElementById("new_description").value;

  if (temp_image && temp_description && temp_title != null) {
    alert("hello world");
  } else if (new_image && new_title && new_description != "") {
    var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
    var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML =
      "<tr class='myrow'><td id='row" + table_len + "'><img id='image_row" + table_len + "' src = " + new_image + "><td id='title_row" + table_len + "' class='titleData'>" + new_title +
      "</td><td class='descData' id='description_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_description + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(this);'><input type='button' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ",this)'></td></td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("new_image").value = "";
    document.getElementById("new_title").value = "";
    document.getElementById("new_description").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <table id="data_table" align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5>
    <tr>
      <th>Image Link</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_image"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_title"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_description"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add" value="SAVE" id="save_btn" onclick="add()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I just wanted is to delete row when the delete button is clicked. It seems the outerHTML has an error since it will return null value. Thanks.

Comment: Please improve your code and provide running fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error as you with your `onclick='delete_row(this);'` pass an object `this`, not a row number.

Instead you could try something like this, where to find the [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) `tr` and delete that, e.g.

```
function delete_row(el)
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
        el.closest('tr').remove();
    } else 
        alert("Data is not deleted");
}
```

---

If to keep your existing delete function, change your `onlick` to this

```
onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ");'
```

I would still recommend the first suggestion, as using `.outerHTML` to delete an element is not that very readable.

Or you could do like this, with `onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ");'`

```
function delete_row(no)
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
        document.getElementById("row" + no).parentNode.remove();
    } else 
        alert("Data is not deleted");
}
```

---

Updated, removed my second suggestion.

Thanks to [Karan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169299/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property/51169373?noredirect=1#comment89322811_51169373), using the existing solution might back fire, and the reason is you are using `(table.rows.length) - 1` to get the `id`.

The issue it can create is you end up with 2 rows having the same `id`.

Comment: Does closest exist in HTML element? or you are referring to jQuery's closest

Comment: as i changed the code to `onclick='delete_row("+table_len+",this)` it will only delete img tag

Comment: @Rajesh No, to javascript `closest()` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: @hazy Well, you can't change to that and then use my updated function. Keep your `onclick` as is

Comment: `onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ");'` this second suggestion can cause issues. As if someone is adding two rows then table will have id `row1` and `row2`. Then delete first row. So single row left with id `row2`, Now again you are adding new row then it will add with id `row2`. So there will be two elements with same id `row2`. `document.getElementById` selector will always select first `row2` element and delete it.

Comment: @Karan Very true, thanks. Didn't notice they pick up the `id` using the length of the rows. Updated my answer